# How to handle database migration scripts in Tornado framework.?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tornado

I have been searching for libraries that can handle database migration for tornado framework. How is the database migration handled in Tornado framework ?

I was working on [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) before and it has a very convenient CLI tool to handle Database migration.

I am looking for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [Alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/). It was originally written to support [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), but you don't need to use SQLAlchemy as long you have a relational database it supports. That said, you will need to understand SQLAlchemy Core to work with Alembic, but that is generally a useful skill to have.